# How to use services to store and retrieve list data in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am having two components "add-expense" component and "view-list" component.
I am getting expense detail from a form in "add-expense" component as an object. I want to append the object to a empty list in "expense-list" service. Later when I load my view-list component all the values in the list at "expense-list" service must be rendered.

I found the method of using rxjs behavioursubject. But most examples are to store a string and update it with .next(). In my case I need a list.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
export class ExpenseListService{
    expenseList:BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]); //error
    
}
```

How to declare a behavioursubject of type list? How to append/push to the behavioursubject list? and how to subscribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting an error that code doesn't generate an error for me
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-f2odgz?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Anyway, if you have a behavior subject of an array and you want to push a new value to it you use the spread operator to generate a new array with the new item.

```
export class ExpenseListService{
  expenseList:BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    
  add(item) {
    this.expenseList.next([...this.expenseList.value, item]);
  }
}
```

This will cause the behavior subject to emit a new array with the new value added.

Comment: Hi, 
I am getting this error when i try to declare expenseList
Type 'BehaviorSubject<never[]>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<any[]>'.

Comment: Make the types match `expenseList:BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);` but instead of any use the real inferface you will be using.

Answer (score 0):

when you assert to the variable when declaring it, you don't need to set the type because it's set the type according to the value you asserted.

so you can write it:

```
expenseList = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

But the best practice is to set the type of the array, you should do it like this:

```
expenseList = new BehaviorSubject<ListModel[]>([]);
```

when you want to append to the existing data you need to it like this:

```
const newValue = 'new value';
const newContent = [...this.expenseList.getValue(), newValue];
                
this.expenseList.next(newContent)
```

to subscribe to it:

```
 expenseList.asObservable().subscribe(() => ....)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I believe you updated your question, so I updated my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Edit: AdrianBrand's Solution is much more clear and fitting and should be preferred

If I understood you correctly, you want to

1. append a single object from the "add-expense" component to an array
2. subscribe to an observable in your "view-list" and get the array with all previously appended values?

Using a BehaviourSubject like you intended won't work, because you would emit a new array each time and loose the previously appended values.

Instead, I think a simple store would be the best solution:
(Beware: This only appends values to the list, if the observable is subscribed to.)

```
export class ListService {
  // No initial value:
  private expenseListSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  // The empty initial array:
  private initialList = [];

  // Pipe the values emitted by the subject through scan and accumulate the values:
  public expenseList$: Observable<any[]> = this.expenseListSubject.pipe(
    scan((acc: any[], currentValue: any) => ([...acc, currentValue]), this.initialList)
  );
  
  public addToList(value: any) {
    this.expenseListSubject.next(value)
  }
}
```

to subscribe in your component:

```
export class ViewList {
  constructor(private listService: ListService) {}
  
  this.listService.expenseList$.subscribe((currentArray) => console.log(currentArray))
  }
```

To append a new value:

```
export class AddExpense {
  constructor(private listService: ListService) {}

  this.listService.addToList(value)
  }
```

Comment: There is no need to mess around with a subject just for the sake of pushing to a scan, this is convoluted when calling next on a BehaviorSubject with an array and the spread operator will achieve the same result. It will also not retain values between subscriptions to the expenseList$ as it will generate a new accumulator for each subscription.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I agree, and if I could, I already would have upvoted your answer (I have too little reputation, which is kind of meaningful in this context ;-) )